# Group Adjacent Functionality in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have a question about the use of `group-adjacent`.

I have seen two patterns being used:

**Pattern 1:**

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::p[@class = 'code'])">
```

**Pattern 2:**

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="@class">
```

Based on what is used, I noticed that `current-grouping-key()` returns a false.

What is the purpose of using a boolean function in group-adjancent ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the form `<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::p[@class = 'code'])">` the grouping key is a boolean value that is true for adjacent `p` elements having the `class` attribute with value `code` while with the second form `<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="@class">` the grouping value is a string and groups all adjacent elements with the same `class` attribute values.

So it depends on your needs, if you have e.g.

```
<items>
  <item class="c1">...</item>
  <item class="c1">...</item>
  <item class="c2">...</item>
</items>
```

you can use the second approach to group on the `class` value.

On the other hand, if you want to identify adjacent `p` elements with a certain `class` attribute, as e.g. in

```
<body>
  <h1>...</h1>
  <p class="code">...</p>
  <p class="code">...</p>
  <h2>...</h2>
  <p class="code">...</p>
</body>
```

then the first approach allows that.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you for responding. This certainly helps me understand the code rather than blindly following a solution posted.

Answer (score 2):

> Based on what is used, I noticed that current-grouping-key() returns a
>   false.

current-grouping-key() returns either true or false, depending on the current group. In your first example, current-grouping-key() will be true for any group of adjacent `p` elements of class "code", false for the other groups.

> What is the purpose of using a boolean function in group-adjancent ?

Without this, the grouping key would be the result of evaluating the expression `self::p[@class = 'code']` which returns an empty sequence, which in turn causes an error.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful Does this mean when boolean function is used, only 2 groups are created (true group and false group) ?

Comment: No, you get a new group every time you find an element for which the condition has a different value from the previous element.